# What happens when I try to read from a pipe without writing to it?

Tags: c, pipe

With this operation I expected to get an error because I'm reading from nothing, but in fact the program seems to keep attempting to read until someone writes to it. If there are no writes it will be stuck in an indefinite loop trying to read and will not proceed.

What exactly happens behind the scene here, do the function kept looping, or is it waiting for a signal, or is something else going on? Is it still taking CPU resources?

Also, is it possible to make the program return an error code/print out something when trying to read without any writes? I don't really need to do it, just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Purpose of pipes is to have one (or more, but be careful) write points and one (or more, but be careful) read points. So one process can read all the time. If there is nothing in the pipe (or queue), nothing is read. When other process writes to pipe, you can read it on *read* side. So it is perfectly valid to read empty pipe (you will read 0 entries).

Comment: The behavior is described in the [relevant man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

Comment: Normally, the read will be a blocking read and will wait for data to appear, or all write ends of the pipe to be closed.  It won't consume CPU time while blocked.  Similarly, writers get blocked when the pipe fills (the capacity varies; classically, it was 5 KiB, but it is often 64 KiB on modern Unix-like systems, though POSIX only demands 4 KiB), or until there is no reader available on the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior.  If nothing is available to read, the reading process will block until there is.  It will not consume CPU time while blocking; the OS will put it to sleep until another process writes to the pipe.

Keep in mind that pipes were designed to be somewhat transparent; a simple filter-type program should not have to care whether the input is a file or a pipe.  If every program that wanted to be able to read from a pipe (think `grep`) had to include special handling to wait until the writer was ready, it would be very tedious for those programmers.  This behavior means that reading from pipes doesn't require doing anything special.

If you don't want to block if no data is available, you can set the `O_NONBLOCK` status flag on the file descriptor, either when you `open(2)` it, or with `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, ...)`.  In this case, when no data is available, `read(2)` will return `-1` and set `errno` to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.  This means, of course, that every time you read from the file descriptor, you have to write code to handle such a case.

You can also use `select(2)` or `poll(2)` to wait until data is available, optionally with a timeout.

It is also possible to arrange it so that a signal arriving during the blocking will cause `read(2)` to return `-1` and set `errno` to `EINTR`.  This depends on system call restarting semantics and is a little bit complicated.